# HTML5 section disappears when on server

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I am currently prototyping a website using Foundation 5. I have a HTML5 section which contains an image, header and repeated background. This displays fine locally but as soon as I move the site over to my web server everything in the section tag disappears. It appears for a split second then disappears.

```
   <section id="banner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Does anybody know why this is occurring? Seems odd that it only happens on the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without having any idea about what you are doing, I can tell there is some Javascript that replaces <section> with something else or removes it entirely.

Comment: Your server is likely not causing this problem, especially if it *"appears for a split-second"*.  Use your browser's inspection tools to look at the DOM.  Verify that the code is just hidden.  Disable your JavaScript and see if it has any effect when you reload the page.  You can also use your browser's tools to inspect the CSS on these hidden elements.  Otherwise, there really is nothing we can do for you with what little you've shown us.  You'll have to employ some basic troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: I am not using any custom Javascript, only the standard Foundation scripts. The code above is still shown in the source code, it's just not displaying.

Edit - thanks Sparky, I will try disabling javascript.

Comment: If JavaScript is not hiding it, then CSS is.  So inspect the CSS within the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Stylesheet (CSS file) has been kept in right folder and CSS path is correct. I have used section tag in my own [HTML5 Tutorial](http://www.html5tutorial4u.com/) website and it is working perfectly. You can visit http://www.html5tutorial4u.com and check the source code of home page. I hope that it will help you a bit.